# PHP Curl stops after some requests

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I have a class that login to a coffee machine. I have a laravel app that "scan" all the coffee machines given in a range of IP address.

The problem is that Curl stops after 39, 128 or even 90 requests. So, I don't know what is the problem or if is a memory leak because PHP and Curl doesn't show any error.

I need advice or tips how to achieve this type of problem. Below is my code.

**CoffeeMachine class**

```
<?php 
namespace Starbucks\CoffeeMachine;
class CoffeeMachine
{
private $url = '';
private $username = '';
private $password = '';

private $session;
private $response;
private $responses;

private $lastMessage = '';
private $lastStatus = FALSE;
private $authenticated = FALSE;

private function setFailStatus($message = '')
{
    $this->lastStatus = FALSE;
    $this->lastMessage = $message;
    return FALSE;
}

private function setSuccessStatus($message = '')
{
    $this->lastStatus = TRUE;
    $this->lastMessage = $message;
    return TRUE;
}

public function __construct($url = '', $username = 'admin', $password = 'admin')
{
    $this->boot();

    $this->url = $url;
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->session = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
}

public function getResponse()
{
    return $this->response;
}

public function login()
{
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url . '/cgi-bin/dologin');
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            'username' => $this->username,
            'password' => $this->password
        )
    );
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    $response = curl_exec($this->session);
    $response = json_decode($response, 1);

    if (!isset($response['response'])) return $this->setFailStatus('Auth with no data...');

    if ($response['response'] != 'success') return $this->setFailStatus('Access denied...');

    $this->response = $response;
    $this->lastStatus = TRUE;
    $this->lastMessage = 'OK';
    $this->authenticated = TRUE;

    return TRUE;
}

public function getDeviceInfo()
{

}

public function logout()
{
    curl_close($this->session);
}
}
```

**Discover method in a range of IP**

```
<?php
public function discover(Request $request)
{
    $from = ip2long($request->input('from', '0.0.0.0'));
    $to = ip2long($request->input('to', '255.255.255.255'));
    $ips = array();

    // CHUNK IN GROUPS OF 10 FOR WAIT 60 SECONDS, BUT NOT WORK
    for($i = $from; $i < $to; $i++) $ips[] = long2ip($i);
    $group_of_ips = array_chunk($ips, 10);

    // TESTED THIS AND NOT WORK
    $default_max_execution_time = ini_get('max_execution_time');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', ((abs($from - $to) * 5) + (count($group_of_ips) * 60)) );

    $machine_ips = array();
    foreach($group_of_ips as $index => $row) {
        foreach($row as $ip) {
            $gs = new CoffeeMachine($ip, 'admin', 'admin');
            if ($gs->login()) {
                $machine_ips[] = $ip;
            }
            $gs->logout();
        }
        sleep(60); // TESTED THIS AND NOT WORK
    }

    ini_set('max_execution_time', $default_max_execution_time);

    /* RETURN THE COFFEE MACHINE IP ADDRESS */
    return $machine_ips;
}
```

Comment: How many Ips are there? and can you count how many seconds your script can run? max_execution_time might be set to 60 seconds.

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg Thanks, max_execution_time is computed with the amount of IPs to discover, for example, 255 IPs * 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

add more error checking. some snippets from my curl wrapper, hhb_curl:

```
    $this->curlh = curl_init ( '' ); // why empty string? PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: curl_init() expects parameter 1 to be string, null given
    if (! $this->curlh) {
        throw new RuntimeException ( 'curl_init failed!' );
    }
```

here i verify that curl_init managed to create a curl resource, if it didn't, i throw a RuntimeException. you should do the same.

```
    $ret = curl_exec ( $this->curlh );
    if ($this->errno ()) {
        throw new RuntimeException ( 'curl_exec failed. errno: ' . var_export ( $this->errno (), true ) . ' error: ' . var_export ( $this->error (), true ) );
    }
```

here, i verify that curl_exec didn't register any errors, else i throw a RuntimeException. you should do the same. (it uses curl_errno($ch) )

```
function setopt_array(array $options): bool {
    foreach ( $options as $option => $value ) {
        $this->setopt ( $option, $value );
    }
    return true;
}
```

here i make sure my setopt_array doesn't actually use curl_setopt_array, but my own curl_setopt wrapper, you should do the same, for reasons explained below.

```
private function _setopt(int $option, $value): bool {
    $ret = curl_setopt ( $this->curlh, $option, $value );
    if (! $ret) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException ( 'curl_setopt failed. errno: ' . $this->errno () . '. error: ' . $this->error () . '. option: ' . var_export ( $this->_curlopt_name ( $option ), true ) . ' (' . var_export ( $option, true ) . '). value: ' . var_export ( $value, true ) );
    }
    $this->curloptions [$option] = $value;
    return $ret; // true...
}
```

here i verify that curl_setopt succeeded, if it didn't, i throw an InvalidArgumentException, you should do the same (or at least throw some kind of exception, rather than the silent ignore your current code does.), and unlike curl_setopt_array, you can actually easily determine which option couldn't be set.

and when debugging curl code, always set CURLOPT_VERBOSE. (hhb_curl always does this, and gives curl a CURLOPT_STDERR tempfile() to put the verbose/error logs in, and gives you the logs through $hc->getStdErr() ), you should at least add some form of CURLOPT_VERBOSE support for debugging. my curl wrapper, hhb_curl, is available here https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php

Answer (score 0):

Adding a timeout to the curl execution solves the problem. You need to monitor the response time for each device you want to reach. for me, 10 seconds for CONNECTTIMEOUT and TIMEOUT works fine.

```
<?php 
namespace Starbucks\CoffeeMachine;
class CoffeeMachine
{
private $url = '';
private $username = '';
private $password = '';

private $session;
private $response;
private $responses;

private $lastMessage = '';
private $lastStatus = FALSE;
private $authenticated = FALSE;

private function setFailStatus($message = '')
{
    $this->lastStatus = FALSE;
    $this->lastMessage = $message;
    return FALSE;
}

private function setSuccessStatus($message = '')
{
    $this->lastStatus = TRUE;
    $this->lastMessage = $message;
    return TRUE;
}

public function __construct($url = '', $username = 'admin', $password = 'admin')
{
    $this->boot();

    $this->url = $url;
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->session = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
}

public function getResponse()
{
    return $this->response;
}

public function login()
{
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url . '/cgi-bin/dologin');
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            'username' => $this->username,
            'password' => $this->password
        )
    );
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($this->session, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    $response = curl_exec($this->session);

    if (curl_errno($this->session)) {
        $msg = $this->url . "\n" . curl_errno($this->session) . "\n" . curl_error($this->session);
        return $this->setFailStatus($msg);
    }

    $response = json_decode($response, 1);

    if (!isset($response['response'])) return $this->setFailStatus('Auth with no data...');

    if ($response['response'] != 'success') return $this->setFailStatus('Access denied...');

    $this->response = $response;
    $this->lastStatus = TRUE;
    $this->lastMessage = 'OK';
    $this->authenticated = TRUE;

    return TRUE;
}

public function getDeviceInfo()
{

}

public function logout()
{
    curl_close($this->session);
}
}
```

Now I can loop and reach CoffeeMachines =)